# Order generator program

Tags: python

I am trying to make a short program which will take user input, append the input to a list and then randomly determine the order of the elements in the list.

this is what I thought out:

```py
from random import choice
 
participants = []
 
prompt = "\nPlease enter players first name: "
prompt += "\nPlease enter 'q' when all players have been entered: "
 
while True:
    user = input(prompt)
    if user == 'q':
        break
        print(f"There are {slot} participants")

    else:
        participants.append(user)
        slot = len(participants)
        print("\n\n")
        for participant in participants:
            print(f"{participant}")
        print(f"So far, there are {slot} participants")

while participants:
    for participant in participants:
        person_of_choice = choice(participants)
        person_in_question = participants.remove(person_of_choice)
        print(person_in_question)
```

However, I am getting the following output

> Mark Stark Dark So far, there are 3 participants
>
> Please enter players first name:  Please enter 'q' when all players
> have been entered: q None None None

How do I change the ordering from none into their names?

Comment: I've edited the formatting. Please double check indentation and take a look as to how to properly format code

Comment: `list.remove` works in-place and returns `None`. You need to `print(person_of_choice)` and not `person_in_question`

Comment: By the way, the line `print(f"There are {slot} participants")` is unreachable. Move it ***before*** the `break`...

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a few things in the code, and the changes are commented out with ##.
you can try it to see the output.

```
from random import choice

participants = []

prompt = "\nPlease enter players first name: "
prompt += "\nPlease enter 'q' when all players have been entered: "
# init slot to zero
slot = 0
while True:
    user = input(prompt)
    if user == 'q':

        print(f"There are {slot} participants")
        ## if you want to use `print` function before `break`,
        ## you must put the `break` statement under the `print` function
        break
    else:
        participants.append(user)
        slot = len(participants)
        print("\n\n")
        for participant in participants:
            print(f"{participant}")
        print(f"So far, there are {slot} participants")

while participants:
    for participant in participants:
        person_of_choice = choice(participants)
        print(person_of_choice)
        # person_in_question = participants.remove(person_of_choice)
        ## person_in_question is None, because `remove` always return None
        ## you can this from here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
        participants.remove(person_of_choice)
```